# CSS-Fading-Transition with Image-Sprite without additional Markup

Tags: css, css-transitions

here ist the almost finished example:
http://jsfiddle.net/mbDAF/

i want a fading-transition with 2s duration between the two images.
but the transition does not work (i am using crome v20).

can someone tell me why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe transitions on generated content aren't supported yet - https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=23209

**Update: *January 4, 2013***
As Benjamin pointed out in the his comment below, transitions on pseudo-elements are starting to become possible. css-tricks.com is tracking the support on different browsers ***[here](http://css-tricks.com/transitions-and-animations-on-css-generated-content/)***.

Comment: finally they come:
http://css-tricks.com/pseudo-element-animationstransitions-bug-fixed-in-webkit/